# python sklearn import failed on libquadmath.so.0 in 3.5.1

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Getting import Error while importing `sklearn` , the only Error code what it says is `libquadmath.so.0` which i'm unale to see on the pkg path but same module works fine in 3.6.1.

```
   >>> import sklearn
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
        from .base import clone
      File "/python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 11, in <module>
        from .utils.fixes import signature
      File "/python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
        from .validation import (as_float_array,
      File "/python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 16, in <module>
        from ..utils.fixes import signature
      File "/python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/utils/fixes.py", line 324, in <module>
        from scipy.sparse.linalg import lsqr as sparse_lsqr
      File "/python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy-0.18.0rc2-py3.5-linux-x86_64.egg/scipy/sparse/linalg/__init__.py", line 112, in <module>
        from .isolve import *
      File "/python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy-0.18.0rc2-py3.5-linux-x86_64.egg/scipy/sparse/linalg/isolve/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
        from .iterative import *
      File "/python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy-0.18.0rc2-py3.5-linux-x86_64.egg/scipy/sparse/linalg/isolve/iterative.py", line 7, in <module>
        from . import _iterative
    ImportError: libquadmath.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Check whether this file exists :/anaconda3/lib/libquadmath.0.dylib

Comment: we are not using anaconda

Comment: check whether that file exist in the python libs